# AzerothCore - How do I fix the error 'Map file does not exist' when starting worldserver on Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon?

Tags: path, azerothcore

I installed everything on Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon 64-bit and when I started the world server it worked for about an hour inserting all of the SQL into the database then gave me the following error:

> Map file '\usr\bin\azeroth-server\etc\Data/maps/0004331.map': does not exist!

Notice the \ where / should be? Where is this path stored so I can change to forward slashes? I assume that's the error, as the map file does exist in `/usr/bin/azeroth-server/etc/Data/maps/`

Thanks in advance for your help

I was following the directions from the AzerothCore website and they are very complete and easy to follow. I remember doing it in the past years ago but it's all a lot easier now since the authserver and worldserver both insert the SQL automatically on the first start.

After that was complete is when the error popped up.

Answer (score 0):

In your `worldserver.conf`, make sure the `DataDir` has the **absolute path** of your data files.

In your case it should be `/usr/bin/azeroth-server/etc/Data/`

(even though it is a bit strange to place your Data files inside `etc`, I would move them to something like `/usr/bin/azeroth-server/data/`).

Sometimes the relative paths create issues.